# Conway's game of life - python: cells wont die

Tags: python

I'm am beginning my journey into the world of python. I have done a couple of small projects, but the game of life really piqued my interest. Unfortunately, when I tried to replicate the game, everything worked except for the death of my cells. Per the rules, if a live cell has less than 2 neighbors, or more than 3, it should die. Cells are being born, but alas, they seem to be immortal. Can anyone spot my mistake? I'm including the entire code because I have no idea where I went wrong.

```
import random, time, copy

height = 10
width = 10
next = []

for x in range(width):
    column = []
    for y in range(height):
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            column.append(" ")
        else:
            column.append("#")
    next.append(column)
while True:
    print("\n\n\n\n")
    current = copy.deepcopy(next)

    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            print(current[x][y], end=" ")
        print()
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            leftco = (x - 1) % width
            rightco = (x + 1) % width
            botco = (y - 1) % height
            topco = (y + 1) % height

            neighbors = 0
            if current[leftco][topco] == "#":
                neighbors = neighbors + 1
            if current[leftco][y] == "#":
                neighbors = neighbors + 1
            if current[leftco][botco] == "#":
                neighbors = neighbors + 1
            if current[x][topco] == "#":
                neighbors = neighbors + 1
            if current[x][botco] == "#":
                neighbors = neighbors + 1
            if current[rightco][topco] == "#":
                neighbors = neighbors + 1
            if current[rightco][y] == "#":
                neighbors = neighbors + 1
            if current[rightco][botco] == "#":
                neighbors = neighbors + 1
                
            if current[x][y] == "#" and (neighbors == 2 or neighbors == 3):
                next[x][y] = "#"
            elif current[x][y] == " " and neighbors == 3:
                next[x][y] == "#"
            else:
                next[x][y] == " "
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: is the first cell in the row is neighbor with the last cell in the same row?

Comment: Add some type of comments stating which variable is doing what because with the code you have provided, it is really difficult to understand what you're trying to do in the code snippet.

Comment: In your own words, where you have `next[x][y] == " "` as a line of code by itself, what do you expect that to do?

Answer (score 0):

In this section, you confused `==` and `=` when you try to assign to a value of `next[x][y]`

```
if current[x][y] == "#" and (neighbors == 2 or neighbors == 3):
    next[x][y] = "#"
elif current[x][y] == " " and neighbors == 3:
    next[x][y] == "#"
else:
    next[x][y] == " "
```

So it should be:

```
if current[x][y] == "#" and (neighbors == 2 or neighbors == 3):
    next[x][y] = "#"
elif current[x][y] == " " and neighbors == 3:
    next[x][y] = "#"
else:
    next[x][y] = " "
```

By the way, you see `next` is highlighted as a special name. That's because [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) is a special function in Python standard library, and you shouldn't name your own variables like that. It's harmless in your current program, because you don't use it, but develop a habit to use more specific names, that don't shadow the standard ones

Comment: When the problem boils down to a simple typo like this, that is an *explicit* (as in, separately listed in the dialog) reason to close the question, rather than answering. Use the comment section to point out these issues.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It's not a typo for the learner point of view. It's a bug of the program worth pointing out IMHO.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a tutorial resource. The point is that questions should potentially be useful *to future viewers* who find them *with a search engine*. While many beginners will make mistakes like this one, it's impossible to help them with a site like Stack Overflow, because there aren't good search terms to use (and even if there were, nobody with the problem would ever think of them). Stack Overflow is for questions that are *understood by the asker* (not the solution of course, but at least the *problem*) in at least some capacity.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I know this policy of SO, and I kinda agree it makes the web-site cleaner. But there are thousands of posts from 10 years ago, where people's questions are like "How to use this function?", and there are millions of views, thousands of up-votes, even though the answer is as simple as opening the documentation. I don't want you to answer this comment, just wanted to point out that Q&A is a broad term, I'd rather help the asker than not.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Thank you so much, I can't believe I didn't pick that up. I know that looking at code and seeing such a rookie mistake can be tedious. I fixed it and the program is working as expected.